# New Year's Resolution

Tags: culture

*New Year's resolution* should be - 新年の抱負

How do I say, "My New Year's Resolution is X"?

For example:

> 私の新年の抱負は気楽になります。(My New Year's resolution is to be more relaxed)

Is it correct?

Do Japanese people normally have New Year's resolutions?

Comment: 気楽になる is not even literal translation for "to be more relaxed". 気楽になること is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes. Many Japanese people make New Year's resolutions. It also can be said ”新年の誓.” Many people write down their New Year's Resolution e.g. "I'll pass the examination of Tokyo University," "I'll save ¥500,000 this year," or "I'll get a fabulous sweetheart," on the first page of a diary. Some people write down their resolutions on plain paper - 半紙 by using a writing brush on January 1st, and hang it on the wall, or enshrine it on 神棚 or 仏壇, wishing the God help them to achieve their resolutions. Alas, in reality, the New Year's Resolutions tend to turn out to be a mere dream for most of us by year's end.

With regard to your translation - 私の新年の抱負は気楽になります - of "My New Year's resolution is to be more relaxed," it sounds like "My New Year Solution is Easy Going," and is a bit awkward in Japanese. I would like to suggest "私の新年の抱負は、何事も気楽に過ごすことです", in other words, 何事があっても平静な気持ちで過ごすことです as an alternative.

Addendum:

Hey. By the way. Time magazine (December 31) carried a very interesting article about how to make your New Year's Resolution come to true under the title, “Here’s the Secret to Sticking to Your New Year’s Resolutions,” in which 
Tory Higgins, a professor of psychology and business at Columbia University gives you a trick for thinking about your resolutions that will make you more likely to keep them. I recommend you take a look at it - http://time.com/4160254/new-year-resolution-success/?xid=homepage.